# HtmlAgilityPack modify html and return updated content

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have not used the HtmlAgilityPack often and I'm stuck on the following issue.

I'm checking to see if the browser supports WebP, if yes I then append a new parameter to the src of the image.

I have that working, but I cannot work out how to return the updated HTML, any help will be appreciated.

```
public static HtmlString AppendWebPString(HtmlString htmlText)
        {

            bool browserSupportsWebP = BrowserSupportsWebPHelper.WebPSupported();

            if (!browserSupportsWebP) return htmlText;

            var h = new HtmlDocument();
            h.LoadHtml(htmlText.ToString());

            const string webP = "&quality=80&format=webp";

            if (h.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]") == null) return htmlText;

            string imgOuterHtml = string.Empty;
            foreach (HtmlNode image in h.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
            {
                var src = image.Attributes["src"].Value.Split('&');
                image.SetAttributeValue("src", src[1] + string.Format(webP));
                imgOuterHtml = image.OuterHtml;
            }

            //How do I return the updated html here
            return new HtmlString(h.ParsedText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not find anything that was built into the agility pack to do what I wanted.

I have managed to achieve what I was after using the code below

```
public static HtmlString AppendWebPString(HtmlString htmlText)
        {

            bool browserSupportsWebP = BrowserSupportsWebPHelper.WebPSupported();

            if (!browserSupportsWebP) return htmlText;

            var h = new HtmlDocument();
            h.LoadHtml(htmlText.ToString());

            const string webP = "&quality=80&format=webp";

            if (h.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]") == null) return htmlText;

            string modifiedHtml = htmlText.ToString();

            List<ReplaceImageValues> images = new List<ReplaceImageValues>();
            foreach (HtmlNode image in h.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))
            {

                var src = image.Attributes["src"].Value.Split('&');
                string oldSrcValue = image.OuterHtml;
                image.SetAttributeValue("src", src[0] + src[1] + string.Format(webP));
                string newSrcValue = image.OuterHtml;
                images.Add(new ReplaceImageValues(oldSrcValue,newSrcValue));
            }


            foreach (var newImages in images)
            {
                modifiedHtml = modifiedHtml.Replace(newImages.OldVal, newImages.NewVal);
            }
            return new HtmlString(modifiedHtml);
        }
```

Comment: Question, whats the reason you are splitting the image.Attributes["src"] for? you are in essence, removing the & sign.